# Authentication firebase всплывает уведомление, что приложение остановлено. android

Tags: java, android, firebase, аутентификация

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    //Это создавать обязательно
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                });



    }

    private void init() {
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Если мы нажали на кнопку с id LogIn сработает определенное условие
        if(v.getId() == R.id.LogIn){
            LogInReg(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.SigIn){
            SingIn(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

        }

    }

    public void SingIn(String email, String password) {
                                                      //Слушатель для выполненого кода
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            //Вроде сработает если авторицация прошла
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                //Если таск завершиться успешно
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Авторизация прошла успешно!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Авторизация не прошла ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void LogInReg(String email, String password){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Регистрация прошла успешно!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Регистрация не прошла ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    }
```

Это в logocat(это все выделено красным):

11-15 17:54:13.505 30550-30550/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.english_day, PID: 30550
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.english_day/com.example.english_day.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:5)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:292)
at com.example.english_day.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Comment: вкладка logcat, там будет много красного текста во время падения, скопируйте его и вставьте его в вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

В `onCreate` поля ввода пусты - активность ещё даже не отображена на экране.
Вызов `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...)` там вообще лишний - юзер у вас регистрируется по нажатию кнопки.
В `onCreate` можно будет сделать авто-логин с сохранёнными ранее логином и паролем.
И в обработчике нажатия кнопки, кстати, стоит проверить содержимое полей ввода, прежде чем отправлять запрос на логин/регистрацию.